# Show that the sequence $a_n = \frac{\sqrt n}{1+\sqrt n}$ is increasing for all n.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that the sequence $a_n = \frac{\sqrt n}{1+\sqrt n}$ is increasing for all $n$.

To prove its increasing I need to show that $a_{n+1} \gt a_n$, however the algebra is quite tricky and I have not been successful, if anyone could give me a hint that would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
Write it as, $$\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n}}=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{n}-1}{1+\sqrt{n}}=1-\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}.$$ Since, $\sqrt{n+1}\gt\sqrt{n}$ it follows that $1+\sqrt{n+1}\gt1+\sqrt{n}$, ... can you proceed further?

Comment: Yup I got it thanks a million :)

Comment: @user2250537 You're welcome! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

$a_n=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+1}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is a decreasing function of $n$. Hence, the denominator of $a_n$ is decreasing for all $n$. So, $a_n$ is increasing for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The reciprocals of the terms are given by $\frac{1 + \sqrt{n} }{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + 1,$ which are _____ (as $n$ increases, $\sqrt{n}$ increases, so $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ decreases), so the terms are _____.

(Fill in each blank with one of the words "increasing", "decreasing".)

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac {\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n}}-\dfrac {\sqrt{n+1}}{1+\sqrt{n+1}}=\dfrac {\sqrt{n}(1+\sqrt{n+1})-(1+\sqrt{n})\sqrt{n+1}}{(1+\sqrt{n})(1+\sqrt{n+1})} <\sqrt{n}(1+\sqrt{n+1})-(1+\sqrt{n})\sqrt{n+1}=\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1}<0$